Get actions from users for quiz bot on discord
I'm kind of new in coding. Thought, i'm working on my second bot. The first one is giving random prompt from a json file to let players imagine their character in new situation to help them to know their character even more.
Anyway. The bot I need help for is a quizbot. For now, I've set up the command to start the quiz with " !quiz " And this is working just fine .
Don't know if this can be an issue later on though. For my first bot I've only used slash command.
My issue here is that the bot is sending the first question with
possible answer on a button but none of those are responding.
The terminal doesn't give me any clue on this and discord tells me "interraction failled" and that's it.
Here is my code so far.
const { Client, Intents, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Client({ intents: [ 'GUILDS',// Required for guild-related events
                                        'GUILD_MESSAGES' // Required for message related events
                                      ] 
                        });
const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

                        // Choose the prefix for starting the quiz
const PREFIX = '!'; // You can change this prefix as needed

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Quiz Bot is ready!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'quiz') {
        // Example quiz question
        const question = 'What is the capital of France?';
        const answers = ['Paris', 'London', 'Berlin'];
        
        // Create button row for each answer
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                answers.map(answer => new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId(answer.toLowerCase())
                    .setLabel(answer)
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                )
            );
        
        // Send question with buttons
        await message.channel.send({
            content: question,
            components: [row]
        });
        // Listen for button clicks
        const filter = (interaction) => interaction.customId === answers.find(a => a.toLowerCase() === interaction.customId);
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 }); // 15 seconds to answer

        // collector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
        //     await interaction.reply({ content: `${interaction.user.username} answered ${interaction.customId}`, ephemeral: true });
        // });
        collector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            try {
                // Différer la mise à jour de l'interaction jusqu'à ce que le bot ait terminé de traiter l'interaction
                await interaction.deferUpdate();
        
                // Traiter l'interaction ici
                await interaction.reply({ content: `${interaction.user.username} answered ${interaction.customId}`, ephemeral: true });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error handling interaction:', error);
            }
        });
        

        collector.on('end', () => {
            message.channel.send('Quiz ended.');
        });
    } else if (command === 'addquestion') {
        // Call the addQuestion command handler
        await addQuestion(message, args);
    }
});

// Replace 'YOUR_TOKEN' with your actual bot token
client.login(token);

What I expect is for the bot to understand someone is clicking on the button and obviously
I'checked if everything was set properly for authorisation in the dev portal. I didn't try admin since it's seems unacessary.
Here is how what I've got looks like :
Screenshot of my bot message with unworking button
I think my issue is that something in the code is missing to get the interaction from user but I don't quiet understant how to set it up
Thanks a lot for your help !

What you could do is setup some emotes with the question, one for each answer, and create some object like this
const player = {
      score : 0,
      id: theUserId
 }

Everytime a user clicks on the emote that represents the answer he gets a point and is added to the list of players if he's not already in it and at the end of the quizz you just set the winner to the highest score

Register user is definetly a step to congrats winner and even more.
But are you implying I can't get reaction from the bot 'cause I didn't code the user yet?
It would actually make sense ..

No, you can start coding and test it by yourself. It's just an idea on how you could implement things.

Discord has a lot of events like MessageReactionAdd and MessageReactionRemove https://gist.github.com/Iliannnn/f4985563833e2538b1b96a8cb89d72bb
You can get the author with reaction.author.user iirc

Thanks I'll check again how messageReaction is working.
But I'd rather works with button than emoji reaction.

Try this then https://discordjs.guide/message-components/buttons.html#building-buttons
